# Dr. Pierre-Marie Robitaille: On the Validity of Kirchhoff's Law

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, thermal-radiation

Lately I've been researching about the black-body spectrum and the historical development of Planck's Law. I mainly wanted to understand a little bit more why many different objects (Stars, Hot Metals) emit a Black-body-like spectrum. I found plenty of things, one in particular was this post :

[Research Gate post on Kirchoff's law](http://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_Kirchhoffs_law_of_thermal_emission_now_dead)

They link to this Video :

[Dr. Pierre-Marie Robitaille: On the Validity of Kirchhoff's Law | EU2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Hstum3U2zw)

**This man claims that Kirchoff's law is wrong**, he says that it's statement is not as general. He claims that it holds only for certain materials with a very high absorption coefficient. He also says that it fails in certain situations where the cavity have a high reflective coefficient Here I post Kirchoff's law:

> **Kirchoff's law:** For a body of any arbitrary material, emitting and absorbing thermal electromagnetic radiation at every wavelength in thermodynamic equilibrium, the ratio of its emissive power to its dimensionless coefficient of absorption is equal to a universal function only of radiative wavelength and temperature. That universal function describes the perfect black-body emissive power. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_law_of_thermal_radiation)

It is true that the the part: *"For a body of any arbitrary material"* is pretty non intuitive. But  I don't have the knowledge to judge whether what he claims is right or not.

The article he speaks about is this one [Kirchhoff’s Law of Thermal Emission: 150 Year](http://www.ptep-online.com/index_files/2009/PP-19-01.PDF)

> **Update:** I also want to know a little bit from the reflectivity coefficient, is it true that Planck forgot to consider it in the derivation of Kirchhoff law ?

Something is definitely right, if his claims are right, there are many unsolved problems in physics in that area. For example all the explanations that I read about why many different objects (Stars, Hot Metals) emit a Black-body-like spectrums relies on the complete validity of Kirchhoff's Law.

Do you know about experimental evidence that support his ideas  ? , Are there other explanations of objects emmiting Black-body-like spectrums that don't relies on this law ?

Comment: The main aspect of this question seems to be "What do you think about this?" which makes it too opinion-based IMO. I think if you reword it to ask about the validity of the physics, it could be better, and reopenable. Also, the title isn't doing you any favors, claiming that a part of established physics is wrong.

Comment: I edited my post to correct the weak points. You didn't watch the video, right ? otherwise you would know that the lecturer is claiming that Kirchhoff law is wrong !

Comment: No, I didn't watch the video, and I shouldn't need to. Questions should be self-contained. In any case, the title you had before made it seem like _you_ were claiming Kirchoff's law was wrong, and that's what that part of my comment was about.

Comment: this might enlighten you http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Pierre-Marie_Robitaille . There was a discussion here on his cosmic  background radiation ideas, which really are bizarre.

Answer (score 4):

Dr. Robitaille says that blackbody radiation is not universal, even inside cavities where the surfaces are all at thermal equilibrium.

That is highly controversial since the electromagnetic fields in a cavity are usually considered as an additional substance, called a "photon gas" which is also at thermal equilibrium and hence has a temperature. This temperature determines all of its properties and leads easily to the black body law.

Leaving aside all considerations of perfectly reflective cavities (unrealistic and can easily lead to divide-by-zero errors in reasoning), let's focus on what he says about weakly absorbing surfaces. In particular I think what he shows on the slide at 25:45 is incorrect (spectrum of a realistic Al oxide particle in a perfectly reflecting box).

Regarding 25:45, let's consider what happens when there is no cavity exit. Consider what happens at any frequency to any light ray bouncing around inside the cavity. At each collision with the particle, the light energy after will be increased by emission ($\epsilon$), but diminished by absorption ($\alpha$).
$$E_{\rm after} = (1-\alpha) E_{\rm before} + \epsilon$$
Now obviously both $\alpha$ and $\epsilon$ will have very complicated dependencies on incident angle, frequency, temperature, position, surface material & contamination, and so on. However Kirchoff's statement is that the RATIO $\epsilon/\alpha$ is independent of angle or material, and only dependent on frequency and temperature. For such a fixed ratio it is easy to see that a steady state must be achieved after many collisions, given by $E_{\rm after} = E_{\rm before} = \epsilon/\alpha$.

Dr. Robitaille seems to be saying the ratio $\epsilon/\alpha$ is not only dependent on frequency and temperature but also on material and angle. However this is not borne out in any experiment I am aware of: it is always seen that $\epsilon/\alpha$ has the universal form. Note that we are leaving aside notions of cavities, the value $\epsilon/\alpha$ can be measured directly on any surface you desire without any ambiguity of cavity geometry.

(Note also that if $\epsilon/\alpha$ were not fixed, then it would not always be possible to reach a steady state of radiation inside the cavity. This seems impossible to me, as a thermodynamic system should always be able to achieve a steady state when all parts are at the same temperture!)

Comment: You are being too kind--indeed inaccurate--by calling it "highly controversial". He's completely wrong and everyone knows it. There's no "controversy" here at all.

Comment: Looks like you're right, Steve. I saw the rationalwiki link anna v posted above, he's not just making a strange misunderstanding of a physics law, but rather there is some weird motivation about disproving the standard explanation of the cosmic microwave background.